# How do I save the parameters of Weibull distribution using "eweibull" function?

Tags: r, weibull

Good Morning,

I am using the "eweibull" function to calculate the shape and scale parameters of a dataset in R. I want to save the found parameters, however the code used is not working. Can someone help me? There is another way to do this?

```
n <- 500
shape <- 1.5
scale <- 0.5
X <- rweibull(n, shape, scale)
(est.par <- eweibull(X))

est.par[attributes(est.par)$par.type=="shape"]
est.par[attributes(est.par)$par.type=="scale"]
```

Comment: If this is the `eweibull` function from package `EnvStats` you should be able to use `est.par$parameters["shape"]` and `est.par$parameters["scale"]` to extract the two parameter values.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!